# Calling self-made Python API with another Python program

Tags: python, linux, api, pipeline

I'm running a local server with my Flask Python program. I am able to GET request the server with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/ -d "input_data=something" -X GET
```

and everything goes well.
However, if I try to call it from another Python program this way:

```
import requests
r=requests.get('http://localhost:5000', json={"input_data": "something"})
```

I get an error:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe3b510a310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

What is the problem here?

Besides, is there a way to insert the server program into a standard Linux pipeline? I mean something along this logic (of course, I know that this concretely doesn't work):

```
cat "something" | http://localhost:5000 > output
```

Comment: try netcat `nc`

Comment: If you have a firewall on your machine you might need to allow/add an exception for the python interpreter / executable.